# Magento2 : Move review to seperate place

Tags: magento-2.1, theme

When I am adding reviews in product page it's showing it in review tab, but I want it in seperate place i.e under the tabs section.How to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just override your catalog_product_view.xml file from core module.

Just keep line in body tag,

```
<move element="reviews.tab" destination="content.aside" before="-"/>
```

keep below content in your xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">   
    <body>       
        <move element="reviews.tab" destination="content.aside" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```